# Unique combinations from a set with duplicates

Tags: python, combinations

In python, when I write:

```
L = [2,2,3]
list(itertools.combinations(L, 2))
```

I get this:

```
[(2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 3)]
```

I want to get only this:

```
[(2, 2), (2, 3)]
```

That is, each combination should appear only once, even though the original list contains two 2's.

What is an efficient way to get each subset of L (of size 2) only once?

**What I tried:**

```
list(itertools.combinations(set(L), 2))
```

returns only:

```
[(2, 3)]
```

This is not good - I want to get the (2,2) too, since it is a subset of L.

```
list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(set(L), 2))
```

returns:

```
[(2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3)]
```

This is not good - I do not need the (3,3), since it is not a subset of L.

Comment: set(itertools.combinations(L, 2))?

Comment: "set with duplicates" - In other words, not a set.

Comment: What if you have `[2, 2, 2, 3]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from more_itertools import distinct_combinations

print(*distinct_combinations([2, 2, 3], 2))
```

Output:

```
(2, 2) (2, 3)
```

[Documentation](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.distinct_combinations), which says:

> Equivalent to `set(combinations(iterable))`, except duplicates are not generated and thrown away. For larger input sequences this is much more efficient.

Comment: Great answer! I did not know about more_itertools.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi Then you didn't read the itertools documentation :-) (it [mentions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) it)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import itertools

L = [2,2,2,3]
print(list(set(itertools.combinations(L, 2))))
```

Output:

```py
[(2, 3), (2, 2)]
```

Comment: This is very inefficient - it might generate many unneeded combinations.